# AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'append'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to append an equation value and gettig error.

> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
>   last)
>
> in
>
> 25 p.append(0)
>
> 26
>
> ---> 27 a.append((p[0]-c*v[0]-k*u[0])/m)
>
> 28 dt = 0.1
>
> 29
>
> AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'append'

```
y = 1/2
b = 1/4


t = []
p = [0,25,43.3013,50,43.3013,25,0,0,0,0,0]

u = []
v = []
p = []
a = []

x = 0.0
for i in range(11):
    a = 0.0 + x
    t.append(a)
    x = x + 0.1

m = 0.45594
k = 18
c = 0.2865

u.append(0)
v.append(0)
p.append(0)

a.append((p[0]-c*v[0]-k*u[0])/m)
dt = 0.1

a.append(m/(b*dt*dt)+y*c/(b*dt))
a.append(m/(b*dt)+(y/b-1)*c)
a.append(((1/(2*b))-1)*m + dt*((y/(2*b))-1)*c)
kn = k + a[1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    x = 0.0
for i in range(11):
    a = 0.0 + x
```

here you are overwriting a, so now it's float not list :)

Answer (score 0):

First you define a list `a = []`, but later you use a temporary variable with the same name, `a = 0.0 + x`, which overwrites the list. Use a different variable name for this temporary.